# probability of similarity of 4 digits from md5 hash of two strings

Tags: probability

Suppose we select four random digits from md5 hash of a string. And we select four random digits from md5 hash of some other string. What is the probability that these 4 digits will be same?

Answer (score 0):

There are $16$ possible characters for each position in a md5 hash. When you select a pair, you are selecting $1$ combination from a list of $16 \times 16=256$ 
 combinations and since we have no information about the strings, we have to consider the selection of each combination as being equally likely. There are $16$ pairs that match in the list of $256$ combinations, so the probability of randomly selecting $4$ pairs (with replacement) that match is $$ \left(\frac{16}{256}\right)^4 \approx 1.52588 \times 10^{-5} $$

It is possible that the md5 algorithm itself may result in some characters having a higher likelihood of occurring than others, but I suppose if you had to take that into account it would make this calculation very much more complicated.